# Basic JSON file management in R

Tags: json, r

**Background**

I got a really nice dataset regrding ALS that I need to access so I can test some very interesting methods of machine learning. The problem is that the dataset is very poorly supported and I lack experience when it comes working with complex datastructures or JSON in R

**What I need**

If someone can help prividing me with actual R code examples (preferable using RJSON or rjsonio) on how I should access the code it would be great. Any basic tutorials/descriptions on how to use JSON with R would also be appreciated as JSON.org is more tailored to people with programming experience using it for programming AJAX/SQL applications.

Data to show my specific problem (dictionary file and data in the text file)
I couldn't post text from the dictionary file so here is a screenshot for it posted on Flrickr
http://flic.kr/p/cSNbpm

The actual data is several thousands of lines long but looks like this:

```
649|144|Demographics|5AC60165-78AA-4E1D-8CCF-F1A21B944A8B|1203|Demographics Delta|0
649|144|Demographics|5AC60165-78AA-4E1D-8CCF-F1A21B944A8B|1204|Ethnicity| 
649|144|Demographics|5AC60165-78AA-4E1D-8CCF-F1A21B944A8B|1207|Race - Asian|
649|144|Demographics|5AC60165-78AA-4E1D-8CCF-F1A21B944A8B|1208|Race - Black/African American|
649|144|Demographics|5AC60165-78AA-4E1D-8CCF-F1A21B944A8B|1211|Race - Caucasian|1
649|144|Demographics|5AC60165-78AA-4E1D-8CCF-F1A21B944A8B|1257|Age|48
649|144|Demographics|5AC60165-78AA-4E1D-8CCF-F1A21B944A8B|1393|Race - Other|
649|145|ALSFRS(R)|B2F1F8AC-6BEA-483C-9BC8-F13C51ED6FFB|1213|1. Speech|3
649|145|ALSFRS(R)|B2F1F8AC-6BEA-483C-9BC8-F13C51ED6FFB|1214|10. Respiratory|4
649|145|ALSFRS(R)|B2F1F8AC-6BEA-483C-9BC8-F13C51ED6FFB|1215|2. Salivation|3
649|145|ALSFRS(R)|B2F1F8AC-6BEA-483C-9BC8-F13C51ED6FFB|1216|3. Swallowing|2
649|145|ALSFRS(R)|B2F1F8AC-6BEA-483C-9BC8-F13C51ED6FFB|1217|4. Handwriting|4
649|145|ALSFRS(R)|B2F1F8AC-6BEA-483C-9BC8-F13C51ED6FFB|1218|5a. Cutting without Gastrostomy|4
```

It seems to be separated into several different section so further down the general structure is changed several times

```
727029|146|Laboratory Data|67962337-62FA-42E3-9E22-1C36965088D6|1234|Laboratory Delta|448
727029|146|Laboratory Data|67962337-62FA-42E3-9E22-1C36965088D6|1250|Test Name|Urea
727029|146|Laboratory Data|67962337-62FA-42E3-9E22-1C36965088D6|1251|Test Result|4.50
727029|146|Laboratory Data|67962337-62FA-42E3-9E22-1C36965088D6|1252|Test Unit|mmol/L
727029|146|Laboratory Data|C2F387B2-00B5-4645-9B2A-03F43117C44B|1234|Laboratory Delta|448
```

Comment: I really don't understand why the XML section has been omitted to ----+---- and only some of the text is interpreted as code.

Comment: It was an xml file to show the dictionary of the text file containing data in JSON format.

The data is available through Innocentive so I am not able to put it up here https://www.innocentive.com/ar/workspace/challengeDetail/432710?challenge=9933047

Comment: So if its XML where does the '|'-separated stuff that you just posted come from?

Comment: It was the dictionary that was locating in a .xml file (you see the actualy dictionary in the image list). The actual data is a .txt file in JSON annotation (the code examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the [rjson package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rjson/index.html) in CRAN.